# Oracle Materialized View Error Log Table?

Tags: oracle

I have a number of materialized views that for various reasons on (rare) occasion will fail to materialize. Is there a database table that stores the error messages from the refresh attempts that I can query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following query to check when the MVs were last refreshed.

```
SQL> select owner, mview_name, last_refresh_type, last_refresh_date
from dba_mviews/user_mviews;
```

If you were refreshing these MVs using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`:-

```
SQL> select log_date, status 
from dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
where job_name='JOB_NAME';

LOG_DATE                                     STATUS
--------------------------------------       ------------------------------
16-APR-17 04.42.58.546973 AM +05:45          SUCCEEDED
08-APR-17 02.38.12.843886 AM +05:45          FAILED
```

If you were refreshing these MVs using Job Queues/DBMS_JOB`:-

```
SQL> select job, last_date last_refresh,next_date next_refresh, total_time,broken, failures, what
from dba_jobs
where what like '%dbms_refresh%';
```

The reason of the job failure is written in `alert_<SID>.log` file as shown below as well as in a trace file referenced in the alert log file.

```
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/orcl_j003_143260.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SCHEMA"."JOB_NAME"
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.PACKAGE/PROCEDURE", line 70
ORA-06512: at line 1
```